# Express $\lg \frac{y}{x^2}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $\lg x^2y = a$ and $\lg \frac{x}{y}=b$,Express $\lg \frac{y}{x^2}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

I did this, I don't know whether it right or wrong!

$\lg x^2y=a$ can be written as: $lgx^2\cdot\lg y=a$

Then: $\lg x^2 = \frac{a}{\lg y}$

and $\lg \frac{x}{y} = b$ can be written as: $\lg y=-b+\lg x$

As I'll have to express $\lg \frac{y}{x^2}$, I made $lg x^2$ and $\lg y$, so now I can substitute the values into $lg \frac{y}{x^2}$.

Is this the right way?

***If I continue in this way, the answer doesn't come right! :'( Help

Comment: What is ${\rm lg}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin What? I just wrote in the way my book wrote...that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful!

$\log(ab) \neq \log a\cdot \log b$. Rather, $\log (ab) = \log a + \log b$.

---

So...$\quad\log(x^2 \cdot y) = a \iff \log(x^2) + \log(y) = a \iff 2\log x + \log y = a$

$\log\left(\frac xy\right) = b $ does give us $\;\log y = \log x - b\;$ you are correct.

And we can express $\log\left(\dfrac y{x^2}\right)$ as $$\log y - \log (x^2) = \log(y) - 2\log x$$

Comment: uh-oh...It must be $\log\frac{y}{x^2}$ :)

Comment: Updated, Kiara! Have you been able to tackle the problem?

Comment: Yeah...thanks a lot! Your answer was really helpful! @amWhy

Answer (score 2):

Your error was $lgx^2\cdot\lg y=a$.